# jQuery .text() not working for dynamically created items like div , span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I received data in `data.d` but it doesn't add data to below element.

**JS**

```
$("#CountUpvote").text(data.d);
```

**HTML**

i want to change text of this span by id

```
<span class="btn_link" id="CountDownvote10">
```

Comment: Provide your html and js code here

Comment: show data.d or data

Comment: i want to change text of this span by id <span class="btn_link" id="CountDownvote10">Downvote </span>

Comment: then why you using CountUpvote id in js ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, [edit] your question and add _all_ relevant information there instead of adding comments. Also, please visit the [help] before posting questions. Thank you.

Comment: use  http://api.jquery.com/on/  for the event which is generating the HTML this will bind the jquery automatically

Answer (score 0):

Either you missed out including jquery or you are not writing your function in document.ready() on delegating an event on which it should add text to the box. 
Check for these issues because the below method works.

```js
$(function(){
  var data = 0;
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    data++;
    $('#countUpVote').text(data);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "button" value="upvote" />
<div id="countUpVote">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you creating some element dynamically, also `data.d` means you have `ajax` call, so In general case, you need to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // the parameters for making ajax working
    success: function(responseFromServer){
       // for creating element using `jQuery` you have 2 options
       // option #1:
        $('<div />', {
            text: responseFromServer.SOME_DATA,
            // you can add class, css, ... to `div` here
        }).appendTo($('SOME_ELEMENT'));

        // option #2
        $('<div />')
           .text(responseFromServer.SOME_DATA)
           .addClass('my-class') 
           .appendTo($('SOME_ELEMENT')); 
    }
});
```

Hope this help.